# I want to add a status bar which should appear at the bottom of the monitor screen varying with monitor size

Tags: java, windows, jframe, statusbar, netbeans-7.4

My query might be so simple but it made me stuck badly.
I'm developing a software using netbeans7.4 and java on windows 8 pc, I have a MainForm which appears on full screen and only shows MenuBar(on top) and label (for background image).
I have used the following code to make it strach as screen size of the user

```
this.setExtendedState(Main_Form.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

now i want to add a status bar which should appear at the bottom of the windows and should identify the location of bottom of the screen itself every time it runs on different size monitor.

Comment: Use a BorderLayout, add a component to the SOUTH position, this will be resized horizontally automatically.  Keep your label in the CENTER position

Comment: can you provide the code? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BorderLayout`, add a component to the `SOUTH` position, this will be resized horizontally automatically. Keep your label in the `CENTER` position

Check out [How to use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

[image: Status]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class StatusBarExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StatusBarExample();
    }

    public StatusBarExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                statusBar.setBorder(
                                new CompoundBorder(
                                                new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY),
                                                new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
                final JLabel status = new JLabel();
                statusBar.add(status);

                JLabel content = new JLabel("Content in the middle");
                content.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(content);
                frame.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                        status.setText(frame.getWidth() + "x" + frame.getHeight());
                    }

                });

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the width of your element equal to width of Clients monitor 
with the command: 
yourelement.Width=ClientRectangle.Width;

Comment: It's not working or may be i'm doing something wrong.